# Wrong page after Login

Tags: asp.net, redirect

If I click on a link(Without logging into the site) I am navigated to this page:

```
http://localhost:59196/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fTest%2fContacts.aspx
```

When I login to the site I want to be redirected to my Home page rather than Test Contacts.aspx page.
How can I resolve this?

If i do this then I'm not logged in.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Home");
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Web Forms, Web Pages or MVC?

Comment: can u share the code of login button click in your Login.aspx codebehind..?

Comment: I fixed it ;) that for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must changed the event.

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change link url you clicking on to:

```
http://localhost:59196/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=Index.aspx
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you clicked on Test Contact.aspx page with out logging in and hence you have been redirected to the Login page with a query string as ReturnURl = test contact.aspx, which might be used to redirect from the login page.

So instead of using return url query string you can redirect directly to your page page from the log in button click in the login page.
Hope it works.

I mean in

```
Loginbutton_click()
{
//login validation code here 
 //after successful validation
Response.redirect("Yyourhomepageurlhere");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect to

```
http://localhost:59196/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fTest%2fIndex.aspx
```

rather than

```
http://localhost:59196/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fTest%2fContacts.aspx
```

In other words the link that you click on should point to the first link above rather than the second.

The question that remains is how are the links generated?  Are they hard coded or are you using MVC and generating the link somehow?  Is the link even in your control to generate?

It would appear your code looks at the ReturnUrl query string parameter and on successful login redirects to it.

Did you come to the Login page from the Contacts page?  If so then the ReturnUrl might have been generated dynamically depending on where you came from.  You may require this to be fixed to being the Index page (I assume this is what you have called it).  Be careful though, other developers may want to have this link be dynamic.

Comment: I used asp.net configuration, and I don't use MVC

Comment: You may require this to be fixed to being the Index page 
How can I set my index page fixed on the redirect